# How to get values of DataDictionary from web page to android

Tags: javascript, android, data-dictionary

I want to parse the data from Html page in Android application. I am sending datadictionary values as below

```
var fields = {"data1" : "1","data2" : "2"};
```

how to get the data1 and data2 values in android application?

**Note: If i passed this fields to MainActivity, i am getting "Object object" and data1 and data2 is imagined, just i want to extract column vice.**

Answer (score 0):

```
  var fields = {"data1" : "1","data2" : "2"};

  try {
    JSONObject json= new JSONObject(fields);

    String data1 =  json.getString("data1");
    String data2 =  json.getString("data2");
  }
  catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: data1 and data2 is unpredictable in source